# How to query unique or distinct values from joining 3 tables which have one to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-cloud-spanner

I wanted to get distinct country values for each category.

Say for example.

A Category has many companies which in turn has many sub-compoanies under it that belong to different counties. Let's say a Cars Category and its companies are Toyota and Honda. And we all know Toyota and Honda are global companies themselves that have branches across the globe.

I wanted to display the unique values of these countries seperated by " | " using string aggr.

How do I go about doing that?

Sample Data:

```
Category table

------------------
ID   |   Name    |  
------------------
1    |  Cars     |    
2    |  Game     |
------------------
```

```
Company Table

---------------------------------------
ID   |  CompanyName    | Category
---------------------------------------
1    |  Toyota         |   Cars
2    |  Honda          |   Cars
3    |  Sony           |   Game
4    |  EA             |   Game
--------------------------------------
```

```
Branches table

--------------------------------------------------------------------
BranchID      |    BranchName     |    Country      | ParentCompany|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | Toyota_America    |    USA          | Toyota       |
2             | Toyota_Japan      |    JP           | Toyota       |
3             | Honda_India_Mumbai|    IN           | Honda        |
4             | Honda_India_Delhi |    IN           | Honda        |
5             | Sony_Japan_Tokyo  |    JP           | Sony         |
6             | Sony_Japan_Hokaido|    JP           | Sony         |
7             | Sony_Spain        |    ES           | Sony         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the example aboev I wanted the output to be:

```
---------------------------------------------
Category   |    Company       |   Contries  |
---------------------------------------------
Car        |  Toyota|Honda    |  USA | JP | IN     
Game       |   Sony |EA       |    JP | ES
```

As you can see in the Sony example, although Japan occured twice, it was only displayed once.

I've tried using the DISTINCT with the joins and string_aggr function but it just doesn't seem to work

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.Category, co.Company, string_agg(br.Country, '|') as Countries 
FROM Category ca
LEFT JOIN Company co ON co.Category = ca.Name
LEFT JOIN Branches br ON br.ParentCompany = ca.CompanyName
Group By
ca.Category, co.Company
```

Now I know that linking them using ID's and whatnot is the best practice but I only made it so, it would be much more understandable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your are missing `group by()`, since you are using aggregate function `string_agg()`

```
SELECT ca.Category, string_agg(co.Company, '|'), string_agg(br.Country, '|') as Countries 
FROM Category ca
LEFT JOIN Company co ON co.Category = ca.Name
LEFT JOIN Branches br ON br.ParentCompany = ca.CompanyName
GROUP BY ca.Category
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the initial question. However I revised it to grouping it according to the Category

Answer (score 0):

In `MSSQL Server`, in order to concatenate you may use either `+` sign or `CONCAT` function. So, in your case you may change the query to something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.Category, co.Company, CONCAT(br.Country, N'|') as Countries 
FROM Category ca
LEFT JOIN Company co ON co.Category = ca.Name
LEFT JOIN Branches br ON br.ParentCompany = ca.CompanyName
GROUP BY ca.Category, co.Company
```

Comment: The string_agg aggregated function that he uses was added in SQL Server 2016

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the tip.